# Decipher a while statement

Tags: c, printing, buffer, sizeof

So I'm editing code and theres a block of code thats totally uncommented so I'm worried about making any changes to it, it all begins with this while statement.

Can somebody decipher this? Describe technically what this is saying/doing, I'm sure I can figure out everything else one I understand this first line.

```
while ( ( cnt = ( long ) fread ( buf, sizeof ( unsigned char ), 16, filein ) ) > 0 )
```

Comment: What bit are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have no idea what this is saying/doing

Comment: im not sure if i'm at liberty to say what i'm working on

Comment: It `freads` from `filein` - casts it to a `long` - assigns it to `cnt` - and if that goes and is greater than zero keep doing something.

Comment: If it helps at all, most operations in C are expressions with an intrinsic evaluation, including an assignment operation. Think of this as: `while ((something-in-these-parens) > 0)`. now ask yourself what that thing is. Its an assignment, which will return the lhs as the expression result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it probably helps to know what [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) does, and what it returns. It tries to read a specified number of objects of a specified size, storing the result in a caller-provided buffer. The return value is the number of objects successfully read.

Now couple that with the fact that assignments in C evaluate as the assigned-value. I.e.

```
int a;
int b = (a = 20);
```

means assign 20 to `a`, the resulting evaluated expression is then assigned to `b`. Since `(a=20)` evaluates as 20, `b` will be 20.

Now look at the code in question:

```
while ( (cnt = (long)fread(buf, sizeof (unsigned char), 16, filein)) > 0 )
```

From the inside-out this does the following:

1. Invoke `fread(buf, sizeof (unsigned char), 16, filein)`. This is requesting a read of up-to 16 items, each of which are the size of an `unsigned char`.
2. Cast the result of that to a `long`
3. Assign that result to `cnt`
4. Compare the resulting expression against zero to determine if it is greater.
5. If it is, the expression is true and the while-loop continues.

This is ultimately a somewhat dusty way of retaining the number of items read from an `fread()` call so it can be used in later code at whatever scope `cnt` is declared.

Answer (score 4):

Let's break it down.

First `fread(buf, sizeof(unsigned char), 16, filein)` is called. This function reads up to 16 of the next bytes from the file designated by `filein`, stores them in `buf`, and returns the number of bytes that were read.

Next, the return value from `fread` is stored in `cnt`. So `cnt` now contains the amount of bytes that were read by `fread`.

Last, the loop checks to see if  `cnt > 0`.

All this put together means that the code will enter the loop if at least 1 byte was read from `filein`. Once inside the loop, `cnt` will contain the number of bytes that were read and `buf` will contain the actual bytes that were read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Keep reading, up to 16 bytes at a time, data from `filein`, until an I/O error of EOF occurs.

```
while ((cnt = (long) fread (buf, sizeof (unsigned char), 16, filein ) ) > 0);
```